# multi browser post issue | duplicated data ! php

Tags: php

I am running a web game based on php , it allows 2 people to open same account , or same player opening 2 browsers for the same account. .

the issue is , I found out there is a bug , when sending an attack people can duplicate their army by one of the following cases :

- they have an app that opens 2 pages at the same time then keep sending same post request of the attack till system accept 2 at same time ,then it will process a double ..
- doing same by enabling airplane mode on phone and send request from 2 pages then disable it and do refresh

when they do it , system will process the request twice and create a double for them

how to block it (make sure for example at least there is a second delay or any other process ) without causing any issues for playing in both browsers ?

Comment: If it was me I'd think about doing this using websockets maybe, and the socket server can check that each player only has one socket open at a time (or at least, only one socket for each battle, if that makes sense for the game).

Comment: You must provide more detail, are you using MySQL database? how you process the requests?